# Carga dinámicamente una librería jQuery, ¿cómo comprobar si antes está cargada?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente estoy utilizando ésta popular función para cargar dinámicamente cualquier tipo de fichero javascript y ahora tengo la necesidad de comprobar previamente si la librería que va a cargar está o no previamente cargada.

```
        //Función carga de librería Jquery vía dinámica.
        var newjquery = 'url'; //Mi aplicación da la url a través de una variable.

        function loadScript(url, callback) {

            var script = document.createElement("script")
            script.type = "text/javascript";

            if (script.readyState) { //IE
                script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        callback();
                    }
                };
            } else { //Others
                script.onload = function() {
                    callback();
                };
            }

            script.src = url;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        }



        loadScript(newjQuery, function() {
            // console.log('Librería cargada.');
            // Aquí ejecutamos el código que la librería necesitaba.
        });
```

¿Qué tengo que añadir para hacer lo que necesito?. ¿Se podría 'eliminar' del head dinámicamente ésta librería tal y como la hemos añadido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más práctico es cargar cada librería asignándole un identificador, de esta manera simplificas las cosas ya que siempre sabes con exactitud qué script borrar.

**Ejemplo**

```js
let scriptsList = document.getElementById('scripts');
let scripts = {
  jquery: {
    id: 'jquery',
    url: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js',
    name: 'jQuery'
  },
  chartjs: {
    id: 'chart',
    url: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js',
    name: 'Chart'
  },
  pdfjs: {
    id: 'pdf',
    url: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/1.7.348/pdf.min.js',
    name: 'PDF'
  }
};

function test(btn, name) {
  let script = scripts[name];
  
  if (!btn.getAttribute('added')) {
    loadJS({
      id: script.id,
      url: script.url,
      callback: () => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = script.name;
        scriptsList.appendChild(li);

        btn.setAttribute('added', true);
        btn.textContent = btn.textContent.replace('Load', 'Remove');
      }
    });
  } else {
    removeJS(script.id, () => {
      let lis = scriptsList.querySelectorAll('li');
      let li = [].filter.call(lis, li => li.textContent === script.name)[0];
      scriptsList.removeChild(li);
      
      btn.removeAttribute('added');
      btn.textContent = btn.textContent.replace('Remove', 'Load');
    });
  }
}

/* Contenido del script de cargado dinámico */

function loadJS({
  id,
  url,
  callback
}) {
  // verificas que no esté cargada
  if (!isAlreadyJSLoaded(id)) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    
    script.id = id;
    script.defer = true;
    script.onload = () => callback();
    script.src = url;
  }
}

function removeJS(id, cb) {
  // verificas que esté cargada
  if (isAlreadyJSLoaded(id)) {
    let script = document.getElementById(id);
    document.body.removeChild(script);
    
    if (cb) { cb(); }
  }
}

function isAlreadyJSLoaded(id) {
  let scripts = document.body.querySelectorAll('script');
  
  return [].filter.call(scripts, s => s.id === id).length === 1;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');


body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 400;
}

li {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

button:first-of-type {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

button:last-of-type {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
```

```html
<h1>List of scripts:</h1>
<ul id="scripts"></ul>

<div style="margin-top: 25px; text-align: center">
<button onclick="test(this, 'jquery')">Load jQuery</button>
<button onclick="test(this, 'chartjs')">Load Chart.js</button>
<button onclick="test(this, 'pdfjs')">Load PDF.js</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantástico, esto es justo lo que necesito porque en un futuro no muy lejano iré ampliando las librerías así como su carga dinámica y su correspondiente retirada al 'salir de la página y entrar en otra'. Perfecto!.

Answer (score 0):

podrías recorrer todos los scripts cargados en tu pagina y comparar contra la url que intentas cargar y en base a eso, insertar el script. Algo así:

```
var isLoaded = function(js_url) { 
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  return Array.from(scripts) // transformo a un array
           .map(s => s.src) // Mapeo a un array con solos los src de los JS ya cargados
           .filter(url => url == js_url) // filtro las url que coincidan con el que se intenta cargar
           .length > 0 // si existe más de una, obvio, está cargada
}
```

y en tu función `loadScript`, al inicio revisar:

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
  if (isLoaded(url)) {
    return callback();
  }

  var script = document.createElement("script")
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  [...]
}
```

Espero haber ayudado

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres evaluar si fue cargada la librería, basta con revisar si existe dentro del espacio de nombres. Por ejemplo, para evaluar si se cargó la librería *easing* de jQuery debes hacer:

```
if ($.easing) { /* Código que depende de la librería */ }
```

(El nombre exacto va a depender de la librería)

Adicionalmente, tienes la opción de usar la función `getScript` de jQuery. Esta carga la librería en base a una url, y tiene métodos para gestionar la carga exitosa o errónea.

```
var url = 'http://dominio.com/scripts/libreria.js';
$.getScript(url).done(function(){
    // código que depende de la librería
}).fail(function(){
    // código que se ejecuta si la carga falló (ej: url incorrecta)
});
```

Si eliges esta opción, te sugiero habilitar la caché de esta función, entonces no te volverá a cargar una librería ya cargada. Para eso, antes de la línea que llama a `$.getScript` debes agregar:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
```