# Inclusión dinámica de ficheros javascript en angular

Tags: angularjs, ui.router

Buenas tardes,

Conforme va avanzando, mi aplicación en angular va teniendo mas y mas ficheros javascript incrustados en el index.html que se carga en todas las vistas.

Mi idea es que esos ficheros solamente sean cargados si es necesario. Se que hay un método para poder hacerlo pero no encuentro información sobre ello aún.

Utilizo "ui.router" para cargas las vistas. ¿Sabéis si existe una manera de cargar los archivos necesarios para cada vista junto con este componente?

Un ejemplo de lo que tengo que cargar (alucinante

```
<!-- ANGULAR APP CONFIG-->
<script src="/angular/app/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/config/config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/config/directives/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/config/directives/nya-bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/config/filters.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/config/routes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- ANGULAR CONTROLLERS -->
<script src="/angular/app/controllers/CoreController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/controllers/AuthController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/controllers/BuilderController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/controllers/AppController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/controllers/ProfileController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/controllers/ToolkitController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- ANGULAR APP CONTROLLERS -->
<script src="/angular/app/controllers/EmpresasController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/controllers/ProjectsController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/controllers/ProductsController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/angular/app/controllers/UsuariosController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- ANGULAR APP EVENTS -->
<script src="/angular/app/hooks/EmpresasHooks.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- ANGULAR FACTORIES -->
<script src="/angular/app/factories/AuthFactory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/factories/AppFactory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/factories/ConfigFactory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/angular/app/factories/ContractsFactory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- LIBS -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
<!-- MOMENT -->
<script src="/angular/components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
<!-- ANGULAR MOMENT -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- MAXLENGTH -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/bootstrap-maxlength/bootstrap-maxlength.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- MAXLENGTH -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/bootstrap-maxlength/bootstrap-maxlength-init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- MAXLENGTH -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/jquery-match-height/jquery.matchHeight-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/lib/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- ZOOM IMAGENES -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/jscollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- SCROLL -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/summernote/summernote.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- SUMMERNOTE -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- SWEETALERT -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SELECT -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP DATETIMEPICKER -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- PNOTIFY -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/pnotify/pnotify.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- AUTOSIZE -->
<script src="/assets/js/lib/autosize/autosize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Estoy leyendo acerca de "RequireJS". En cuanto tenga más información lo comento.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53469/26302). Creo que puede aplicar en tu caso.

Comment: Otra opción es usar una librería de carga dinámica de módulos como RequireJS. Yo te recomiendo CommonJS, es más sencillo y más usado. Es el que usa Node.js por defecto (hasta que V8 implemente soporte para módulos ES6).

Comment: Estoy mirando webpack y parece bastante útil. El problema es que uso ES5 y no hay casi nada de información para lo que necesito

Comment: Si fueses a usar Webpack, ¿para qué quisieras escribir código ES5 si **webpack compila** `ES6+` **a** `ES5` **por ti**?

Comment: No te recomiendo webpack, porque AngularJS trabaja con ES5. Lo único que necesitas es implementar `CommonJS`, `RequireJS` o `UMD` en tu proyecto.

Comment: Por lo que veo con babeljs lo transforma si. Es un poco lioso la verdad :S

Comment: Si quieres que te explique algunas cosas, abre una sala e invítame para hablar al respecto.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo Gustavo. Esta es la sala: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55374/angularjs-aplicaciones-modulares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es este plugin: https://oclazyload.readme.io/

Aqui un ejemplo de como seria tu codigo

```
$stateProvider.state('index', {
  url: "/", // root route
  views: {
    "lazyLoadView": {
      controller: 'AppCtrl', // This view will use AppCtrl loaded below in the resolve
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html'
    }
  },
  resolve: { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
    loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
      // you can lazy load files for an existing module
             return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/AppCtrl.js');
    }]
  }
});
```

Ejemplo tomado de https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router

Comment: Este plugin junto a webpack es efectivamente lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Me alegro haberte ayudado :)